# Scipy - generate light & heavy tailed normal distribution

Tags: scipy, statistics

My goal is to replicate this plot in Python:

[image]

I'm experiencing difficulty in generating light and heavy tailed distributions. The rest, I know how to generate. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try e.g. `gennorm`, the generalized normal distribution. It has a shape parameter which controls the tails.